# Implementing an algorithm that walks the DOM without recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom, iteration

Here's a simple algorithm that walks the DOM given a node:

```
function walkDOM(n) {
    do {
        console.log(n);
        if (n.hasChildNodes()) {
            walkDOM(n.firstChild)
        }
    } while (n = n.nextSibling)
}
```

I wanted to implement it iteratively as an exercise, and came up with this:

```
function walkDOM2(n) {
    var recStack = [];
    // First get the parent of the given node, so that
    // you can get the siblings of the given node too
    // (starting from the last sibling),
    // rather than just start with the children of the
    // given node.
    // (This is to make this behave the
    // same way as the recursive one.)
    recStack.push(n.parentNode);

    while (recStack.length > 0) {
        var current = recStack.pop();
        // Log only if the current node is
        // the given node or a node below it.
        // (This is to make this behave the
        // same way as the recursive one.)
        if (current != n.parentNode)
            console.log(current);
        if (!current.hasChildNodes())
            continue;

        current = current.lastChild;
        do {
            recStack.push(current);
            // Skip the sibling nodes
            // before the given node.
            // (This is to make this behave the
            // same way as the recursive one.)
            if (current === n)
                break;
        } while (current = current && current.previousSibling);
    }
}
```

I have used a couple tricks to make it behave the same way as the first recursive version. Is there a more concise way of writing this without recursion?

Answer (score 9):

I know you are doing this as an exercise, and personally I like the recursive function. But just as an alternative, there is also the much forgotten <kbd>[TreeWalker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/treeWalker?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/treeWalker)</kbd>.

> **Browser compatibility**
>
> Supported by IE9+, FF2+, Chrome 1+, Safari 3+, Opera 9+

Javascript

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.getElementById("list"), NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, {
    acceptNode: function (node) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
}, false);

do {
    console.log(treeWalker.currentNode);
} while (treeWalker.nextNode());
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ttgn7/)</kbd>

Comment: This is very nice... there's just one fly in the ointment for practical use: in the `acceptNode` method (method of `NodeFilter` interface, it seems) there appears to be no easy way of getting the depth of the node passed as the parameter.  Shame - non-recursive tree traversal is usually preferable because of memory questions, etc.

Comment: limitation: this works only in the browser, not in nodejs

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that is about as concise as your recursive solution. (8 lines of code.)

```
  function walkDOM2(n) {
    var stack = [n];
    while (stack.length > 0) {
      var node = stack.pop();
      console.log(node);
      stack = stack.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes, 0).reverse());
    }
  }
```

Some notes on the above:

- After you pop an item off the end of the stack, you replace it with it's children.
- The children are reversed so that the first child is placed at the end of the stack, so it will be the next node to be popped.
- Use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` to turn the `childNodes` NodeList into an Array so it can be added to the stack with `concat`.
- There is no `hasChildNodes()` check, but sometimes there will be no child nodes and an empty array will be added to the stack.

Comment: Can you explain why your alternative version is better than the original version?

Comment: Ooh, *clever*. I hadn't thought of this as a DFS problem. You deserve more upvotes!

Comment: I do wonder if it's possible to do the append-all-reversed in a better way. I'm not nearly familiar enough with javascript to know.

Comment: @Hosch250 which original version are you referring to? The one with recursion? The original poster was asking for a concise solution without recursion: that's what I was going for.

Comment: @o11c I don't know about a better way, but some may find this easier to read: `for (var i = node.childNodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { stack.push(node.childNodes[i]); }`

Comment: Very nice... please see my slight variation on this theme, in which you can get the depth of each node as you iterate...

Comment: PPS also there is a slicker way to do the reversing and adding of the child nodes in ES6: `stack.push( ... Array.from( node.childNodes ).reverse() );` - no reassignment of `stack`, so `stack` can be `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version that uses [iteration](/questions/tagged/iteration) rather than [recursion](/questions/tagged/recursion). It uses [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue), [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), and a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

> **Avoid using labels**
>
> Labels are not very commonly used in JavaScript since they make
>   programs harder to read and understand. As much as possible, avoid
>   using labels and, depending on the cases, prefer calling functions or
>   throwing an error.

Javascript

```
function walkDOM(root, func) {
    var node = root;

    start: while (node) {
        func(node);
        if (node.firstChild) {
            node = node.firstChild;
            continue start;
        }

        while (node) {
            if (node === root) {
                break start;
            }

            if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
                continue start;
            }

            node = node.parentNode;
        }
    }
}

walkDOM(document.body, function (node) {
    console.log(node);
});
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8T8WS/)</kbd>

Finally, here is a <kbd>[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-iterative-dom-walking)</kbd> of the Recursive vs Iterative methods.